# Multi-column index with jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

Say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
  index         serial primary key,
  segment       int not null,
  definition    jsonb not null
)
```

And the `definition` column looks like:

```
{
  "array": [
    { "name: "Bob", "age": 21 },
    { "name: "Alice", "age": 31 }
  ]
}
```

I would like to be able to index a query such as

```
select * from items
where segment = 4 and definition->'array' @> '[ { "name": "Bob" } ]'::jsonb
```

Is it possible to index this query, and what should the index look like? I don't need to query by `segment` + `age`, only `segment` + `name`.

Comment: Your `definition` field looks like a correlated table. A you sure you want it in `jsonb` and not in a separate table?

Comment: The benefit of jsonb is that I can update an entry by only updating one row, as opposed to a potentially large number of inserts, updates and deletes if I had a separate table.